# Flutter Sign In how to show FirebaseAuthException message with Snackbar

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, authentication, firebase-authentication

I made a login page and auth with firebase, In this case at Login page i want to validate form, if user input wrong Email or Password than `FirebaseAuthException` massage to be shown on snackbar. I follow saveral tutorial like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-designing-email-authentication-system-using-firebase/) , but after i try is just getting some `FirebaseAuthException` massege on console and app get freez not printed on snackbar. I will appreciate if someone help me through this.

This is my Authentication Service

```
class AuthenticationService with ChangeNotifier {
  final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  //AuthResultStatus _status;
  bool _loggedIn = false;
  bool get loggedIn => _loggedIn;

  String userUid;
  String get getUserUid => userUid;

  Stream<User> get authStateChanges => firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

  Future<String> logIntoAccount(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await firebaseAuth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      _loggedIn = true;
      User user = userCredential.user;
      userUid = user.uid;
      print(userUid);
      notifyListeners();
      return "Signed In";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        return 'No user found for that email.';
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        return "Wrong password provided for that user.";
      } else {
        return 'Something Went Wrong.';
      }
    }
  }
```

and this the Button on LoginPage

```
 Widget buildLoginBtn() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          _isSubmitting == true
              ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor:
                      AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                )
              : ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _login,
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: kWhiteCalm,
                    onPrimary: kDarkGreenColor,
                    onSurface: kGreyColor,
                    elevation: 5.0,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'LOGIN',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFF527DAA),
                      letterSpacing: 1.5,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _login() {
    final _form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (_form.validate()) {
      _form.save();
      //print("Email $_email, Password $_password");
      _LoginUser();
    } else {
      print("Form is Invalid");
    }
  }

  _LoginUser() async {
    setState(() {
      _isSubmitting = true;
    });

    final logMessage =
        await Provider.of<AuthenticationService>(context, listen: false)
            .logIntoAccount(emailController.text, passwordController.text);

    logMessage == "Signed In"
        ? _showSuccessSnack(logMessage)
        : _showErrorSnack(logMessage);

    //print("I am logMessage $logMessage");

    if (logMessage == "Signed In") {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          PageTransition(
              child: HomeScreen(), type: PageTransitionType.bottomToTop));
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isSubmitting = false;
      });
    }
  }

  _showSuccessSnack(String message) async {
    final snackbar = SnackBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      content: Text(
        "$message",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
      ),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
    _formKey.currentState.reset();
  }

  _showErrorSnack(String message) {
    final snackbar = SnackBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      content: Text(
        "$message",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
      ),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
    setState(() {
      _isSubmitting = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `Provider.of<AuthenticationService>(context, listen: false)
            .logIntoAccount(emailController.text, passwordController.text); `

the above line returns a Future, and you are doing a string operation on that?
It could be like:
`Provider.of<AuthenticationService>(context, listen: false)
            .logIntoAccount(emailController.text, passwordController.text).then((responseString) {
 responseString == 'Signed In' ? _showSuccessSnack(responseString)
        : _showErrorSnack(responseString);
        });`